# Is it possible to use .Where in Model on MVC Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 2 table Models,

First Table:

```
public class tbl_mpDets
{
    [Key]
    public int mpd_Id  { get; set; }
    public int mp_Id   { get; set; }
    public int dpBrand { get; set; }
    public int tKrila  { get; set; }
    public int tPrecka { get; set; }
    public decimal? dpKol { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public decimal dpShirina { get; set; }
    public decimal dpVisina  { get; set; }
    public string dpLorR     { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("dpBrand")]
    public virtual tbl_mehBrand tbl_mehBrand { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("mp_Id")]
    public virtual tbl_mpMas tbl_mpMas   { get; set; }
    public virtual tbl_mehTip tbl_mehTip { get; set; }

    public string tip1 { get; set; }
    public tbl_mpDets(tbl_mehTip objtbl_mehTip) =>
        tip1 = (tbl_mehTip.sirOd <= dpShirina && tbl_mehTip.sirDo >= dpShirina) ? tbl_mehTip.tCode.ToString() : -1; // -1 is a default value
}
```

Second Table:

```
public class tbl_mehTip
{
    public tbl_mehTip() => tbl_mpDets = new HashSet<tbl_mpDets>();

    [Key]
    public int tip_Id { get; set; }
    public int sektor { get; set; }

    public int tBrand    { get; set; }
    public string tName  { get; set; }
    public string tCode  { get; set; }
    public decimal sirOd { get; set; }
    public decimal sirDo { get; set; }
    public decimal visOd { get; set; }
    public decimal visDo { get; set; }
    public decimal tCena { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("tBrand")]
    public virtual tbl_mehBrand tbl_mehBrand { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("tBrand")]

    public virtual ICollection<tbl_mpDets> tbl_mpDets { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in First  Model, i need to get Value by checking parameters with `.Where` extension, and select correct value from Second.

Example:

```
// I need some code like this if is possible!
public string Nametip1 => tbl_mehTip.tCode.Where(tbl_mehTip.sirOd <= dpShirina && tbl_mehTip.sirDo >= dpShirina)
```

If is possible please for help, or anyone another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It not possible because `tbl_Table2` that used in `Name` property is a `class` not `object`. You can do it by a constructor like below:

```
public class tbl_Table1 
{
    [Key]
    public int mpd_Id { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }


    public tbl_Table1(tbl_Table2 objTbl_Table2) =>
        Name = (objTbl_Table2.SizeFrom <= Size && objTbl_Table2.SizeTo >= Size) ? objTbl_Table2.NameOfElement.ToString() : "-1"; // -1 is a default value
}
```

Comment: I Tried this solution, but i have this error:
Error CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'bool' to 'System.Func<char, bool>'

Comment: @MisterXP `tbl_Table2.NameOfElement.Where(tbl_Table2.SizeFrom <= Size && tbl_Table2.SizeTo >= Size)` is not correct syntax.

Comment: @MisterXP I used it in my answer as a example. I don't know your purpose by using this code.

Comment: Thank you, But i put the code in my model and i get thet Error.

Comment: @MisterXP if you explain about how `Name` should be set, I can help you better.

Comment: hm... I have anther error with new code, **Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'int'**. Do you have any Idea what can be the problem ?

Comment: @MisterXP You should use `.ToString()`. Again, I edited my code. Please see it.

Comment: Same again. Nothing Changing :(

Comment: @MisterXP This error comes from converting two properties in your code. Please update your question with new code that I can see it and figure out a solution.

Comment: @ Ali Soltani -  I Updated the Question with Fullfill Original codes from Models. Maby can clearli understand. Thank you.

Comment: @MisterXP You forget changing -1 to “-1” in the end of the code and it causes this error

Comment: Thank you @Ali Soltani  - Now has not error in code, but on preview now i have this error. **The class 'MehanizmiApp.Models.tbl_mpDets' has no parameterless constructor.** do you see where is problem in model ? Error is on Details page        at  `foreach (var item in Model.tbl_mpDets)`

Comment: Thank you again. My problem is solved by another way, but your code and way help me to solve. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you could have this code in controller. instantiate `tbl_Table1` and `tbl_Table2` and assign X property like this :

```
tbl_Table1.X = tbl_Table2.NameOfElement.Where(tbl_Table2.SizeFrom <= Size && tbl_Table2.SizeTo >= Size)
```

Comment: It's better you use backticks for your code or use short key ( CTRL+K ).

Answer (score 0):

first you must use `lambda expression` in Where clause.

```
tbl_Table2.NameOfElement.Where(x=> x.SizeFrom <= Size && x.SizeTo >= Size)
```

also, you must connect to database with `context` and retrieve data from there or use factory of models, or something like a list.

therefor use something like this :

```
var Name = context.tbl_Table2.Where(x=>x.SizeFrom <= Size && x.SizeTo >= Size).FirstOrDefault()?.Name;
```

Comment: I think your code it's not appropriate in this case because @Mister needs to set `Name` when creating new instance of `tbl_Table2`.

Comment: i Forgot in question to put, But in real code exist Name instance. :)